# Why does Windoes not allow the subnet to be the same as the subnet mask?

Tags: networking, subnet

In Windows, I can configure a network adapter like this:

```
Ip Address: 192.0.0.1
Subnet Mask: 224.0.0.0
```

but not like this:

```
Ip Address: 192.0.0.1
Subnet Mask: 192.0.0.0
```

Why?
Why can't the subnetwork be the same as the subnetwork mask?

Comment: You should not configure your machine to use that 128.0.0.1 IP. That's a public internet address, and a quick [lookup](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/128.0.0.1) indicates it's assigned somewhere in Romania. I don't think it belongs to you. You need to use an IP from one of the reserved private ranges: 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, or 192.168.0.0/16

Comment: lol .. I'm not using this IP on my network. I'm developing an app that has to validate the network entered by the user, before configuring the windows adapter, and I'm trying to see what IP address windows accepts, so I can inform the user if windows is going to accept that configuration.

Comment: @Hauke Laging 128.0.0.1 is a valid IP for a network adapter on windows

Comment: It would probably be a very good idea to read up on network and subnetting first.

Comment: @MadHatter Sorry, I misread that and deleted my comment.

Comment: Ok, jeez, ignore my previous example. Consider this 192.0.0.1 224.0.0.0 works, 192.0.0.1 192.0.0.0 doesn't. Why?

Comment: It's not a duplicate ... jeez

Comment: Yeah, realised that as I posted it, hence the deletion, I'm now trying to find out what the OS may dislike about that IP/netmask combination

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with the fact that everything past 223.x.x.x is either multicast or reserved. Windows will not allow you to put anything above 223 in the first octet of the IP field. The 224.0.0.0 subnet above covers 192.0.0.0-223.255.255.255, however using a 192.0.0.0 netmask goes into the multicast/reserved area.

Comment: It appears Windows will accept that netmask with a lower IP (so the top end of the range doesn't go above 223.x.x.x) Also of note, Windows doesn't seem to like values where the entire network or host portion are 0 either

Comment: Oh, you're right, it goes into multicast if subnet = mask. Thanks Matt

Comment: Please don't edit "answers" into questions. That's not how this site works. See http://serverfault.com/about for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
128.0.0.0/1 = Block of 128  = 1000 0000.0000 0000.0000 0000.0000 0000

1st Subnet - 0.0.0.1 --> 127.255.255.254
2nd Subnet - 128.0.0.1 --> 255.255.255.254
```

So, your 1st subnet encompasses the loopback address (127.0.0.1) and your second subnet (the one you're trying to use encompasses the multicast and reserved ranges.  My guess is Windows isn't going to allow you to do this because of potential problems.  I'm not sure why it's even letting you use a `/2`.  Regardless of the technical aspects... what the heck are you trying to accomplish by using a `/1`!!

Comment: With /1 you have a **huge** lot of hosts... :-)

Comment: I'm building an app that validates user network configuration before it tries to apply it. So I'm considering valid whatever windows accepts.